# how to get current script file name in R Script

Tags: r, rscript

i run file test.R in RStudio.

how can i get full path (include file name) or just the file name of the current script : test.R

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are not using `rscript` (hover over the tag for more info).

Comment: hii,
i cant understand why you think i dont use rscript ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rscript/info

Comment: Because running a script in RStudio is not the same as using the `rscript` binary.

Comment: thanks.

i used commandArgs() and find the source :)